# Конкатенация ключей и значений словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, список, словарь

Передо мной стоит задача написать программу для вывода всех объектов и их типов репозитория git.
Я пытаюсь решить задачу так:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint as pp

def getHashes(git):

    subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(d) if f.is_dir() ]
    INFO = subfolders.index('.git/objects/info')
    PACK = subfolders.index('.git/objects/pack')
    subfolders.pop(INFO)
    subfolders.pop(PACK)
    objL = []
    _hash = []
    for i in subfolders:
        objL.append(str(i).replace('.git/objects/',''))
        _hash.append(os.listdir(i))
    fullHash = dict(zip(objL,_hash))
    return fullHash


d = '.git/objects/'
objects = getHashes(d)

#pp(objects)
```

Мой вопрос состоит в следующем: как правильно обойти словарь так, чтобы при наличии у его ключа более чем одного значения, каждый раз выполнялась конкатенация этого ключа и значения?
Это необходимо для получения полного хэша объекта и правльного выполнения фрагмента

```
os.system('git cat-file -t полный_хэш_из_словаря')
```

Comment: То есть, ваш вопрос сводится к конкатенации значений ключей словаря? Тогда зачем нам знать про git и все остальное? Было бы намного полезней знать, что значения ключа, например, хранятся в списке, и конкатенировать их надо, например, через "пробел"...

Comment: Здесь акцентируется внимание на гит из-за его способа получения полного хэша. Полный хэш берется из имени папки + имя файла в ней содержащейся. И это и надо конкатенировать, чтобы получить сплошную строку. Имя папки представляется в гите 2 символами и их надо соединять с именем файла, который в значении-списке в словаре